# ISN initial sequence number

Tags: tcp

I had a bug that indexed into a buffer that preceeded the buffer containing a SYN packet and it dropped a byte into the ISN of this packet. Unfortunaely even though the packet was sent I got nothing back from the other end. Now this surprised me. I didn't think the other end cared how this ISN was calculated, just that it should be difficult for someone to guess??. Surely not every TCP/IP software has the same calculation such that the other end flagged this one as an invalid packet?!?

Please can some kind soul explain this to my ignorant self.

nb. I believe the packet is going onto the wire as:
1. Wirehark displays it and
2. the light on my network card winks at me.
Othrwise I mght have thought my machine checked the ISN and stopped it.

I guess I'd not make the grade of a Security analyst if I cant understand this, hey!

Comment: Are you doing raw socket I/O? Otherwise there is no way a buffer indexing problem in user mode can have any effect on the TCP ISN, which is in the kernel's address space.

Comment: Rats! I was led astray by wireshark which didn't report a bad tcp header checksum. Once I [realized] and recalced the cecksum with the bad seq no. all was well. EJP - Thank you for your input. I was learning my way using the ndsprot WDK sample.